# Shipping Table Rate, not sum weight

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, table-rates

Using the Table Rate dispatch all the weights of the products are added together and the result is calculated based on the table.

For a specific ecommerce project, where every single product is individually packaged, I would need the shipment to be calculated individually on each product and the added cost (not the added weight)

It's possible? do you need an external module? tips?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this extension [Shipping per Product](https://amasty.com/shipping-per-product.html)

Comment: But this seems only needed to enter a flat rate on the individual product.

Comment: i think not working flate rate for specific product, above link extension working, i have used in past this extension

Comment: it says: "Indicate individual flat shipping rate for each product"

Comment: I heard the assistance via chat. They told me no that's what I'm looking for.